# Можно ли использовать selenium, но не открывать браузер?

Tags: python, selenium

Использую selenium на windows 10. ЯП- python . Можно ли не открывая браузера работать с selenium?

Comment: Возможно вы имеете в виду headless browser, например, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)?

Comment: Chrome тоже умеет уже в headless моде работать. Просто запускайте с опциями `options.add_argument('headless')` Вот тут всё есть [Using Headless Chrome with Selenium](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-headless-chrome-with-selenium)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смею предположить что именно безглавые режимы работы вам и нужны))) Так как использовать селениум без браузера в принципе, это наверное какая-то новая техника о которой я не знаю))))

В принципе сейчас можно запустить Хром и Файрфокс в режиме headless, или использовать PhantomJS.

Если вам необходимо взаимодействовать с сайтом, или запарсить информацию, **но не скачивать файлы**, то хорошим вариантом будет PhantomJS. Всё что вам нужно это просто запустить его, автор создал его как раз для работы в строке, и поэтому никаких режимов запуска к нему приписывать не нужно, вот пример:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

ua = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
ua["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36")
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=ua)
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Второй вариант, это Chrome в режиме `headless`. Так как изначально браузер работает в графическом представлении, при его запуске этот режим нужно указать:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

ua = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x935')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

**Однако 1.** Для загрузки файлов в headless Хроме, нужно немножко потанцевать с бубном, так как Google решили отключить стандартную функцию загрузки в headless режиме, и загружать файлы можно используя DevTools, это обсуждалось вот здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219676/selenium-chrome-headless-download-file и там есть ссылка на баг-трекер.

**Однако 2.** Но это ещё не всё, в headless режиме не получиться использовать расширения, если вам к примеру нужен блокировщик рекламы, или переключатель proxy, или что угодно другое) увы, но пока `headless` режим в Хроме близок к PhantomJS.

Третий вариант, это Firefox в режиме `headless`. Но я к сожалению не могу вам сейчас показать как это делать, так как режим добавили в 56-ой (нынешней) версии для Windows, и я ещё не успел опробовать его. Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь на стаке уже попробовал FireFox и сможет дополнить мой ответ, или написать свой)